# Rotating a 3D object using the mouse to create frictionless momentum

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, rotation

I want to create a visualization of a 3D object where I can vary the speed and direction at which the object rotates by the direction and speed in which I swipe the mouse pointer while holding down the mouse button.  I want the object to continue to rotate indefinitely.  Do you know of a way to do this?  I'm not sure if its possible.

I want something like what you see in the gif below .

[image]

Comment: Have you seen `Rotate`? `ViewPoint`? Do you know how to use `Dynamic`? etc., information that is useful for anyone who wants to provide an answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I am familiar.  I think my issue is that I don't know how retrieve the values from the pressing the mouse button down and the speed at which the mouse pointer is moving across the screen.  If I can grab those, I should be able to put something together.  I'm wondering whether someone has done this already... or if its something that maybe can't be done because of limitation in Mathematica.

Comment: Take a look at `EvenHandler` `ViewPoint` `ViewVector` etc etc, check also this site for related keywords.